# Какую технологию использовать для чата?

Tags: php, node.js, websocket

У меня есть сайт на php, какую технологию мне использовать для чата, workerman,noje.js и soket.io, чат до 2000 человек.
Везде пишут что php не предназначен для сокетов и лучше использовать, node.js, но тогда разрастается стек технологий, а в другом случае пишут, что надо будет грамотно распределять нагрузку на сервер. Но почему именно не стоит использовать php, если есть готовые библиотеки для веб сокетов, какая технология из приведенных все таки подойдёт, и что из этого безопасней?

Comment: Используй что тебе более понятно и удобно.